# Checking if file actually is an Excel file using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm using EPPlus in C# to read an Excel (.xlsx) file. The initialization is done like this:

```
var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filename));
```

This works fine but is there any way to check if the specified `filename` or `package` is actually a valid .xlsx file? Otherwise there will be exceptions when operating on a non-Excel object, e.g. if the user accidentially opens a .zip file or else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the extension of your file:

```
string file = @"C:\Users\Robert\Documents\Test.txt";

string extenstion = Path.GetExtension(file);
```

*Update*

I havent found some kind of return values for the situation that some file cannot be open in the EPPlus documentation, but you can use this to catch the excetptions:

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(pathToYourFile);

ExcelPackage package = null;
try
{
    package = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo);
}
catch(Exception exception)
{
   ...
}
```

If you are not in `catch` - thats mean it was opened correctly.

Comment: Yes, but this does not detect if the file is an Excel in a binary way, right?

Comment: @Robert - cant you just test it on your computer?

Comment: @Robert - or do you think, that binaries havent any extension? )

Comment: Of course binaries can have an extension. What I meant was the following... Example: If any non-Excel file, e.g. a ZIP file is renamed to .xlsx then just checking the extension would not help much. Instead the file can, of course, not be processed.

Comment: @Robert - right - if someone renamed it it will not work.. but Ill search also for this problems solution - and Ill post my feedback here.

Comment: Sure thing, I can catch the exception. Sometimes the solution is too obvious ;-)